# Swift for loop is creating new objects

Tags: swift, struct

I'm working on a game where I store my player objects in an array. I want to give these players a hand of cards and I do so in the following way:

```
var players = [Player]()

mutating func deal(count: Int) {
    for var player in players {
        for _ in 1...count {
            if let card = deck.draw(){
                player.addCard(card: card)
            }
        }
        if (player.id==1){print(player)}
    }
    print(players[0])
}

struct Player{
    var id : Int
    private(set) var randomValue: Int = 0
    private(set) var hand = [PlayingCard]()

    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
        randomValue = 100.arc4random
    }

    mutating func addCard(card: PlayingCard){
        hand.append(card)
    }
}
```

The problem is the hand is not actually being updated. Printing the player at index 0 (player.id == 1) inside the for loop gives me exactly what I expect. However, the print outside the loop has an empty hand and the random number is different. So I know the loop is creating a new object since init is called. Why is this happening and how can I edit the actual object in players array?

Comment: tried it as a class ???

Comment: The syntax ```players[index].addCard(card: card)``` will modify the player struct inside the players array. You need to iterate the players array so you have the index of the player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`player` is struct, when you iterate `players` - you get a copy of the players in the array.
You update it, print it and see the correct result, but it's scope is for the `for` loop only.
Either make `player` a class or update your array with the new copy of the `player`.